# How to fix invalid references after a delete_all

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following relationship:

```
class Blog
  belongs_to :owner
end

class Owner
  has_one :blog, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and by mistake, instead of using `destroy_all` I used `delete_all`. Now I have a bunch of invalid references in the database. How can one fix that?

Comment: so you are just looking for a blog that doesn't have an owner ID now?  Or an owner ID that doesn;t exist?

Comment: You should add foreign key constraints inside your database to keep this sort of thing from happening again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following query from `rails dbconsole`:

```sql
delete from blogs where owner_id not in (select id from owners);
```

Comment: is that mysql??

Comment: Yes. Should work for postgtes and many other databases too.